# Split time into intervals

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have three input

1. Start time
2. End time
3. intervel time.

Example

```
start time - 01:00 
end time  - 01:30 
intervel-time  - 10 min
```

**I need the output like  01:00, 01:10, 01:20, 01:30**

i have tried this below code, its not working .

```
<?php

$startTime=strtotime("2012-07-13 01:00:00");
$endTime=strtotime("2012-07-13 01:30:00");

$time=$startTime;
while ($time < $endTime) {
    echo date('H:i:s', $time) . " - ";
    $time = strtotime('+10 minutes', $time);
    echo date('H:i:s', $time) . "<br>";
}

?>
```

When i try with start and end time interval is 60min, the above code is work.

I am new in PHP.

Any one please help me.

Comment: How is this not working for you? Is the output format incorrect or what?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$startTime = new DateTime("2012-07-13 01:00:00");
$endTime = new DateTime("2012-07-13 01:30:00");

while ($startTime < $endTime) {
    echo $startTime->format('H:i:s') . ' - ';
    echo $startTime->modify('+10 minutes')->format('H:i:s') . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this with DateTime and DateInterval:

```
<?php
$startTime = new DateTime('2012-07-13 01:00:00');
$endTime = new DateTime('2012-07-13 01:30:00');

while($startTime <= $endTime) {
    echo $startTime->format('H:i:s') . ' ';
    $startTime->add(new DateInterval('PT10M'));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code works just fine, i've just added a variable which idicates the interval and reformatted the time in order to be the same as `I need the output like 01:00, 01:10, 01:20, 01:30` and the last thing is that you should first print the time the increment it so.

Here is the code:

```
$startTime=strtotime("2012-07-13 01:00:00");
$endTime=strtotime("2012-07-13 01:30:00");
$interval = "10";
$time=$startTime;
while ($time <= $endTime) {
    echo date('H:i', $time) . "<br>";
    $time = strtotime('+'.$interval.' minutes', $time);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the code works as expected... Maybe you could refactor it like this to have the exact output you are requiring:

```
<?php

$startTime=strtotime("2012-07-13 01:00:00");
$endTime=strtotime("2012-07-13 01:30:00");
$intervel="60";

$time=$startTime;
echo date('H:i', $time);
$time = strtotime('+'.$intervel.' minutes', $time);
while ($time <= $endTime) {
    echo "," . date('H:i', $time);
    $time = strtotime('+'.$intervel.' minutes', $time);
}

?>
```

If you change from 10 to 60 the interval, then it will only print the start time because the start_time+60 is higher than the end time; is this what you'd expect?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with [modify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php), [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php).

```
$startTime = new DateTime('2012-07-13 01:00:00');
$endTime   = new DateTime('2012-07-13 01:30:00');
$endTime   = $endTime->modify( '+1 minute' );
$interval  = new DateInterval('PT10M');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($startTime, $interval ,$endTime);
foreach($daterange as $res) {
        echo $res->format('H:i') .", ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2012-07-13 01:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2012-07-13 01:30:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
while($start <= $end) {
    echo $start->format('H:i:s'), "\n";
    $start->modify('+10 minutes');
}
```

You were missing the last possible output as that would yield the same value as your end-time.
`a < b` should have been `a <= b`

Result: http://3v4l.org/8eK3O