# laravel 5.6 start time end time duration

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a function in Laravel 5.6

I have a `$start_time`, `$end_time` and `$duration` variables.

I would like to get time slots from the start time until end time, in `$duration` periods, for example:

```
$duration = 30 min     
$start_time = 9:00 am
$end_time = 9:00 pm
```

---

Results:

> -9:00 - 9:30
>   -9:30 - 10:00
>   -10:00 - 10:30
>   .... etc

Also, I would like to not show the slot where time overlaps with appointments in my database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split time into intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550025/split-time-into-intervals)

Comment: Hi David, I am looking to make time blocks, [9:00 - 9:30], [9:30 - 10:00] ...  and not intervals.  I am also looking to not show the blocks that overlapps with appointments in the database.

Comment: So consider them as `(startTime, startTime+inteval)`. Can you please add example input and excepted output? and it will be much help to see how you represent appointments in your DB...

Comment: So i get $startTime from database as  09:00:00   and $endTime as 21:00:00

$duration = 00:30:00  

output should be   
  09:00:00 - 09:30:00
 09:30:00 -  10:00:00
10:00:00 - 10:30:00 

exept now i have an appointment with appointment_start value of 09:30:00  and appointment_end value of 10:00:00 , so i  need to hide this slot  in my loop results

Comment: so follow @ahmed answer and just filter the result array according your DB values of appointment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $starttime = '9:00';  // your start time
    $endtime = '21:00';  // End time
    $duration = '30';  // split by 30 mins

    $array_of_time = array ();
    $start_time    = strtotime ($starttime); //change to strtotime
    $end_time      = strtotime ($endtime); //change to strtotime

    $add_mins  = $duration * 60;

    while ($start_time <= $end_time) // loop between time
    {
       $array_of_time[] = date ("h:i", $start_time);
       $start_time += $add_mins; // to check endtie=me
    }

    $new_array_of_time = array ();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array_of_time) - 1; $i++)
    {
        $new_array_of_time[] = '' . $array_of_time[$i] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$i + 1];
    }
```

Comment: This looks great to show the loop from $start_time to $end_time, 

i showed result on blade by doing foreach ($array_of_time as $t)  {{t}} endforeach ,  

Do you have any clue on how can i show   [ 9:00 - 9:30] [ 9:30 - 10:00] . as output and not just [9:00] [9:30] ... ???

Comment: Perfect works great, now the only thing left is to not show the slots where there is already an appointment that overlapps. 

$appointment_start = 2018-09-09 10:30:00
$appointment_end 2018_09_09 11:00:00

Comment: you should put your efforts also. i have answered original question to get you started

Comment: Thankyou a lot for your answer it really did help a lot. This was also in the original question last line, i seriously have no clue on how to hide those overlapping datetime, and it would make a huge difference in the code.  Thankyou again

Comment: make an array of times which contain the appointment by looping over appointments and extracting time out of date. compare that array using in_array method while creating the new_array_of_time array, if in_array returns true, use continue to skip to next iteration in for loop while making new_array_of_time array

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel there is a dependency for times&dates called Carbon I'm sure you've heard of.

all you have to do is importing it like that:

```
    use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Then we can see what will we do by this dependency, we just create a time then add minutes to it according to duration, that is what you want to.

```
    $start_time = Carbon::createFromTime(9, 0, 0);  // hours, minutes, seconds
    $end_time   = Carbon::createFromTime(21, 0, 0);

    $time       = $start_time;
    $time_slots = array();

    while($time < $end_time){
       $time = $time->addMinutes(30);
       $time_slots[] = $time;
    }
```

This array will have the time slots you want and you can manipulate them whatever you like.

You can also look at this links below:

Documentation: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

String formats for Carbon: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thankyou for your answer,  if I want to display these slots in blade,  i need to make a foreach loop ?   foreach ($time as $t)    .. {{$t}}  endforeach ?

Comment: Of course, yes ... your time slots will be kept in array and you can deal with it as a normal , one dimensional array.

Comment: Actually this is the new error i get right now :

Call to a member function addMinutes() on string

Comment: EDIT -- I edited to .  $time = Carbon::parse($time)->addMinutes(30);
but now  look at the result = 

 2018-09-09 09:30:00   ,  i get only one result . and not the loop